# UIButton Bug? (Xcode Version 4.6 (4H127))

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton, xcode4.2, ios6

1st: Xcode Version 4.6 (4H127), simulator 6.1

So... i do the following.
My button (inherited from UIButton) loaded from nib. Then i've set image to it for UIControlStateNormal.
I've got something like this:
[image: button]

After that i need to nullify it:

```
[button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

then i see this: 
[image: wrong_button]

Check diffs:

[image: button]

[image: wrong_button]

So the title layouted right, but the image still there...

Also, if i do following:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I get result like the second one, but without an image (as expected, but not fully, without layouting):

[image: new_image]

I am really interested in what is happening here?
Its really interesting, mb Apple broke something? Or i've just doing all wrong? But i've done it many times(setting image->nil), all worked Okay.

Thank you for reading :) I would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a sample code regarding this.

Your both calls worked me fine

```
 [self.myCustomButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self.myCustomButton setImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I think, you may set the `BackGroundImage` instead of `image`.

[image]

Sample Methods

```
-(IBAction)removeImage:(id)sender{

    [self.myCustomButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[self.myCustomButton setImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(IBAction)setImage:(id)sender{

    [self.myCustomButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Disable.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you **Ramshad** for your response, but i wrote exactly what i'am doing. If i'd set backgroundImage, my backgroundImage should stretched to the bounds of my button. But i've calling setImage, so its not happened. 
I've mannually recreated button, but i'am strongly get this bug.
Hope will find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This thing was here:
My subclass of UIButton overrides -layoutSubviews, where setting imageView.hidden using some criteria.
So, if hidden property was YES, when i've calling setImage:forState - this bug happened.

My fix was next:
I just start using alpha property instead of hidden. (I know that is dirty, but this is the fastest way i've found)